# Stylistic usage of "of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, functions

What is the meaning and function of the word "of" in the following sentence:

> The Americans **of** all nations at any time upon the earth have probably
>   the fullest poetical nature.

I think it is very stylistic, and here I am not sure what the writer means. Does he mean the Americans "among" all nations?

Comment: Why do you this this usage is idiomatic?

Comment: If it is not so tell me what is the meaning of "The Americans of all nations". The problem is it doesn't make sense if you read it in normal way.

Comment: To my mind, ***of all nations at any time upon the earth*** is just an "adverbial clause" - same as, for example, ***above all*** (which has pretty much the same meaning in context anyway), and ***in particular***.

Comment: Just to be clear, it probably should be punctuated as "The Americans, of all nations at any time upon the earth, have probably the fullest poetical nature."  "Of all nations ..." is a parenthetical.

Comment: @HotLicks Yup. You nailed that one. Until I saw your comment I had had problems trying to parse the sentence.

Comment: @HotLicks So what is the meaning of "of all nations"? Does it mean "among" all nations?

Comment: Of all nations at any time upon the earth, the Americans have probably the fullest poetical nature.  IOW, take all the nations that are or ever were and compare them, and you will see that Americans are the most poetical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "of" is a simple qualifier denoting what the comparison is between.

> I have the highest salary **of** people in my family.

means that comparing all the people in my family I have the highest salary.

> The Americans have the fullest poetical nature **of** all the nations.

has a similar meaning.

The sentence you are reading simply reverses the order:

> Of all the nations, the Americans have the fullest poetical nature.

I prefer the version with the comma, but the version without means the same. The full sentence just claifies which nations we are talking about (all at any time upon the earth) and adds the qualifier "probably".